org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.NotYetReadyException: CDI BeanManager not (yet) ready to use
I am facing an issue while upgrading my BAS application from Java 8 to Java 17.
I have also upgraded hibernate from 5.3.29.Final to 6.5.0.final
I am using OpenLiberty version 24.0.0.4 with this configurations in my server.xml
<feature>cdi-4.0</feature>
<feature>jakartaee-10.0</feature>
<feature>persistence-3.1</feature>
<feature>microProfile-6.0</feature>
<feature>messaging-3.1</feature>
<feature>appSecurity-5.0</feature>
<feature>beanValidation-3.0</feature>
<feature>persistenceContainer-3.1</feature>
<feature>servlet-6.0</feature>

I am getting this error inside openliberty server logs
[ERROR   ] CWWJP0015E: An error occurred in the org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider persistence provider when it attempted to create the container entity manager factory for the mpce persistence unit. The following error occurred: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter: org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.NotYetReadyException: CDI BeanManager not (yet) ready to use
Can anyone help me with this?
I have tried these solutions so far but nothing worked
have tried several approches to solve this issue

By delaying Hibernate's attempt to access CDI until it's fully initialized. We did this by adding the following property in persistence.xml

<property name="hibernate.delay_cdi_access" value="true"/>

Providing the BeanManager instance directly to Hibernate
For this created a BeanManagerProvider class that provides the CDI BeanManager instance
Then added the following property in persistence.xml
<property name="hibernate.cdi.beanmanager" value="com.example.BeanManagerProvider.getBeanManager"/>

Checked compatibility of of Jakarta EE and CDI with Hibernate ORM 6.5.0.Final.
we are using cdi v4 , openliberty 24.0.0.4 and jakarta ee10 which are compatible with this hibernate version.


I am expecting that hibernate should initialize after the CDI bean manager is ready to use

I think this can be resolved by setting the property com.ibm.websphere.jpa.hibernate-cdi-compatibility to true.
If it helps you can reference the test server here in our build infrastructure that tests hibernate integration that depends on that property: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/tree/integration/dev/com.ibm.ws.cdi.third.party_fat/publish/servers/cdiThirdPartyServer
Regards
Benjamin
